# String.java with error "Cannot resolve symbol" during compilation

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have a problem when I decrypt a message with the ISO-8859-1 character set. I have a class that encrypts and decrypts. This is the code:

```
public class AES64 {

    public static String encrypt(String key, String ivs, String value) {
        try {
            IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(ivs.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"));

            SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"),
                    "AES");
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5PADDING");
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skeySpec, iv);
            byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(value.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"));
            String r = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(encrypted);
            return r;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    public static String decrypt(String key, String ivs, String encrypted) {
        try {
            IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(ivs.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"));

            SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"),
                    "AES");
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5PADDING");
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, skeySpec, iv);
            byte[] original = cipher.doFinal(Base64.getDecoder().decode(encrypted.getBytes("ISO-8859-1")));

            return new String(original);

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            Log.d("ERRORE",ex.toString());
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

When I decrypt the string and I use the method

```
getBytes("ISO-8859-1")
```

the string contains not a **à** char but an **?** char. So I go to the `getBytes` definition and in the file *String.java* there are many errors. Here is the method:

```
public byte[] getBytes(String charsetName) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    return getBytes(Charset.forNameUEE(charsetName));
}
```

Here is the error:

> Cannot resolve symbol fonNameUEE()

My Gradle file is:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.3'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.fd.ts"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 16
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.ksoap2-android:ksoap2-android:3.6.0'
    compile 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v2.2.5'
    compile 'com.viewpagerindicator:library:2.4.1@aar'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.2.0'

}
```

PS: In the String.java Android studio cannot import libcore.utils.CharSetUtils;

Comment: Please post the full logcat

Comment: There aren't error in logcat, the app run on phone but getBytes not return correct string form

Comment: The result of encryption is 8-bit bytes not characters. It is not a good idea to try and encoded encrypted data into any character set. Generally if encrypted data needs to be encoded into characters Base64 or hexadecimal is used. Note: `ISO-8859-1` is definitely a call back to the past and this is simply a mis-use.

Comment: The string that i want to decrypt is a web service response that use ISO-8859-1 charset. I'he tried to use the same class to a simple java application and it works fine and the string is correct,but in android "à" not recognized.

Comment: Note that the ISO-8859-1 charset handles Base64 encoded data just fine.

Comment: The problem is in the file String.java not in my class, in this file there are 24 errors, but i don't understad how android studio compile this file.

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
return getBytes(Charset.forName(charsetName));
```

instead of

```
return getBytes(Charset.forNameUEE(charsetName));
```

Charset class does not seem to have the method `forNameUEE()` in Android version of Java, did you get the method from some other, non-Android project maybe?

---

EDIT:

As the method seems to be compiled and out of reach, try using

```
ivs.getBytes(Charset.forName("ISO-8859-1"));
key.getBytes(Charset.forName("ISO-8859-1"));
```

instead of passing the `Charset` name :-) You will probably want to get this Charset object once and reuse it for optimization sake, but try it like this first :-D

Comment: The method getBytes is in String.java not in my class

Comment: Updated the answer :-)

Comment: I tried Charset.forname() , but the result not change.
I try to InvalidateCaches and restart but nothing change

Comment: And the logcat output, does it change? Are there still errors in the String.getBytes() method?

Comment: In the file String.java class CharsetUtils not imported, so there are many errors in this class (Java class)